# Counter not reaching value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code for counters. I've noticed that the counter doesn't always reach the higher values (specifically 5500) - adjusting the speed doesn't to fix the problem. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

```js
startCounter();

function startCounter() {
  var hT = $('.value').offset().top,
    hH = $('.value').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height();
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > hT + hH - wH) {
    $(window).off("scroll", startCounter);
    $('.value').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      jQuery({
        Counter: 0
      }).animate({
        Counter: $this.text()
      }, {
        duration: 3500,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter) + '');
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="value">5500</span>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example? Click the edit button and  select code snippet

Answer (score 3):

I've added the complete callback, exactly the same as step callback. The thing about step is that it is executed to manipulate the tween, this means it is not called at the end of the animate (aka when you reach the wanted value)

```js
startCounter();

function startCounter() {
  var hT = $('.value').offset().top,
    hH = $('.value').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height();
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > hT + hH - wH) {
    $(window).off("scroll", startCounter);
    $('.value').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      jQuery({
        Counter: 0
      }).animate({
        Counter: $this.text()
      }, {
        duration: 3500,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter) + '');
        },
        complete(){
          $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter) + '');
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="value">5500</span>
```

Comment: This is great thank you. Unfortunately it seems to stop the animation starting on scroll.

Comment: I have only included the RELEVANT part of the code. On snippets, it's pretty hard to scroll... You can add it back to your code now, the scroll does not have impact on this.

Comment: Thank you again for your help.